# What's the reason why Yosef HaTzadik had to go through slavery?

Tags: yosef, genesis-bereishith

Just a question out of curiosity: What's the reason why Yosef had to go through slavery? What do the sages/scholars say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"For slandering them that they called their brothers slaves, he was sold as a slave" ([Rashi Breshit 37:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.37.2.4))

Answer (score -5):

Yosef is the sefira of Yesod, foundation, which corresponds to the reproductive organ. Like a seed begins the spoiling process when it's dead and buried, then attains a resurrection, so too is the action of Yesod. You can read more about basic "Kabbalah" concepts this answer is based on, in books like Tomer Deborah, L. Moharan, Sefer Yetzirah, and so forth. Why are there sefirot at all? What is the "breaking of the vessels?" What does it mean the sefirot were unable to receive from each other? It's this like what they say of R's Akiba's students that they were unable to practice courtesy to one another? It's basically a lack of middot. Why did the brothers have to be jealous? I don't have the answers but you can find them there and in your personal devotions.

Comment: It is extremely dangerous for someone without an exceptionally solid base to learn kabbalah - we see the confusion and misunderstandings it can lead to here. You basically say a whole bunch of kind of vague things and end off that you have no idea what it means - while it sounds deep and profound, it is very misleading.

R' Aron Lopiansky explains it very well, I reccomend listening to the Q & A in this Google drive (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YTYqq4IKdFgjG3mi77vOSdJyIQENADGa/view?usp=sharing), the question is around the 4:50 mark.

Comment: @KovyJacob The BIH regularly included basic kabbalistic terms and teachings in his public sermons and they're included in his Halakhot. Please respect our tradition.

Comment: Who is the BIH? Also I don't think what I'm saying is a total contradiction to those, such as chassidim, who learn more kabbalah. For one to venture of on their own learning esoteric subjects that they don't fully grasp and will likely confuse them is not a good thing.

Comment: Nobody is assuming I or the reader is learning on his own except you. BIH == Ben Ish Chai

Comment: At the very least one has to have a rebbi/mentor giving them a strong derech of how to learn these subjects, and someone that they can ask questions to and clarify what they don't understand. I assume from your name that you are Breslov, and I am most certain that the 'tradition' of Breslov isn't hefkeirus, untethered from a mesorah and mehalech.

Comment: It is clear from your answer... Without knowing anything about kabalah, it is clear from how you are writing that you don't understand what you are writing. If you can sum it up as 'It's basically a lack of middot' and then go on to say that you don't have the answers I would tend to strongly side with the second statement, hence what I am saying.

Comment: It really can't hurt to listen to what R' Aharon Lopiansky says in that Q & A - you don't have to become Litvish, but I think it could provide an understanding of what the risks of learning kabalah are, thereby enabling you to take steps to avoid them. Not that you should then stop, but you should have an understanding of what can go wrong, so you can then objectively examine everything and decide if you need to get a madrich for this, maybe stop learning that for now, etc.

Comment: The point was I was guiding the asker of the question to study the Sefarim in proper order and manner and thus arrive at an answer to a not stand-on-one-foot question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150244/discussion-between-kovy-jacob-and-nissim-nanach).